# How to flatten JSON with nested structure before passing to @csv filter

Tags: nested, jq, flatten

I am trying to parse some JSON that is the output of an AWS CLI command to display Snapshots.  I want to load this data up into a spreadsheet to be able to filter, group, and audit it.

I've been stumped on how to get the nested Tags array flattened into the parent objects such that the intermediate can then be passed to the @csv filter.

Here is the example:

**Initial input JSON:**

```
{
  "Snapshots": [
    {
      "SnapshotId": "snap-fff",
      "StartTime": "2014-04-01T06:00:13.000Z",
      "VolumeId": "vol-fff",
      "VolumeSize": 50,
      "Description": "desc1",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "/dev/sdf",
          "Key": "device"
        },
        {
          "Value": "a name",
          "Key": "Name"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Internal",
          "Key": "Customer"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Demo",
          "Key": "Environment"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Brand 1",
          "Key": "Branding"
        },
        {
          "Value": "i-fff",
          "Key": "instance_id"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "SnapshotId": "snap-ccc",
      "StartTime": "2014-07-01T05:59:14.000Z",
      "VolumeId": "vol-ccc",
      "VolumeSize": 8,
      "Description": "B Desc",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Value": "/dev/sda1",
          "Key": "device"
        },
        {
          "Value": "External",
          "Key": "Customer"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Production",
          "Key": "Environment"
        },
        {
          "Value": "i-ccc",
          "Key": "instance_id"
        },
        {
          "Value": "B Brand",
          "Key": "Branding"
        },
        {
          "Value": "B Name",
          "Key": "Name"
        },
        {
          "Value": "AnotherValue",
          "Key": "AnotherKey"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired Intermediate:**

```
[
  {
    "SnapshotId": "snap-fff",
    "StartTime": "2014-04-01T06:00:13.000Z",
    "VolumeId": "vol-fff",
    "VolumeSize": 50,
    "Description": "desc1",
    "device": "/dev/sdf",
    "Name": "a name",
    "Customer": "Internal",
    "Environment": "Demo",
    "Branding": "Brand 1",
    "instance_id": "i-fff",
  }
  {
    "SnapshotId": "snap-ccc",
    "StartTime": "2014-07-01T05:59:14.000Z",
    "VolumeId": "vol-ccc",
    "VolumeSize": 8,
    "Description": "B Desc",
    "device": "/dev/sda1",
    "Customer": "External",
    "Environment": "Production",
    "instance_id": "i-ccc",
    "Branding": "B Brand",
    "Name": "B Name",
    "AnotherKey": "AnotherValue",
  }
]
```

**Final Output:**

```
"SnapshotId","StartTime","VolumeId","VolumeSize","Description","device","Name","Customer","Environment","Branding","instance_id","AnotherKey"
"snap-fff","2014-04-01T06:00:13.000Z","vol-fff",50,"desc1","/dev/sdf","a name","Internal","Demo","Brand 1","i-fff",""
"snap-ccc","2014-07-01T05:59:14.000Z","vol-ccc",8,"B Desc","/dev/sda1","External","Production","i-ccc","B Brand","B Name","AnotherValue"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following jq filter produces the requested intermediate output:

```
.Snapshots[] | (. + (.Tags|from_entries)) | del(.Tags)
```

Explanation: `from_entries` converts the array of key-value objects to an object with the given key-value pairs.  This is added to the target object, and finally the "Tags" key is removed.

If the "target" object has a key that also appears in the "Tags" array, then the above filter will favor the value in the "Tags" array.  You may accordingly wish to change the order of the operands of "+", or resolve the conflict in some other way.

Comment: Man.. I danced all around this solution but I was never there.  Thank you so much!